# Master turning into slave after redis sentinel failover

Tags: kubernetes, redis, master-slave, redis-sentinel

I am trying out redis master slave replication using sentinels.
I have 1 master and 2 slaves and 3 sentinels. All running as different pods.

My issue is:

1) When I delete the master pod, one of the slaves turns to master.

2) Ideally, there should be a new master now with only one slave. For some reason, the master IP that I deleted turns into a slave of the newly elected master.

3) Is this a desirable behaviour? Because when the sentinel shows there are 2 slaves to the newly elected master, in fact there exists only 1 slave pod because the master pod is deleted.

Below are the logs:

```
:M 29 May 2020 07:32:19.569 # WARNING: The TCP backlog setting of 511 cannot be enforced because /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn is set to the lower value of 128.
8:M 29 May 2020 07:32:19.569 # Server initialized
8:M 29 May 2020 07:32:19.569 # WARNING you have Transparent Huge Pages (THP) support enabled in your kernel. This will create latency and memory usage issues with Redis. To fix this issue run the command 'echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled' as root, and add it to your /etc/rc.local in order to retain the setting after a reboot. Redis must be restarted after THP is disabled.
8:M 29 May 2020 07:32:19.569 * Ready to accept connections
8:M 29 May 2020 07:33:22.329 * Replica 172.16.2.12:6379 asks for synchronization
8:M 29 May 2020 07:33:22.329 * Full resync requested by replica 172.16.2.12:6379
8:M 29 May 2020 07:33:22.329 * Starting BGSAVE for SYNC with target: disk
8:M 29 May 2020 07:33:22.330 * Background saving started by pid 12
12:C 29 May 2020 07:33:22.333 * DB saved on disk
12:C 29 May 2020 07:33:22.334 * RDB: 2 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
8:M 29 May 2020 07:33:22.355 * Background saving terminated with success
8:M 29 May 2020 07:33:22.356 * Synchronization with replica 172.16.2.12:6379 succeeded
8:M 29 May 2020 07:33:23.092 * Replica 172.16.4.48:6379 asks for synchronization
8:M 29 May 2020 07:33:23.092 * Full resync requested by replica 172.16.4.48:6379
8:M 29 May 2020 07:33:23.092 * Starting BGSAVE for SYNC with target: disk
8:M 29 May 2020 07:33:23.092 * Background saving started by pid 13
13:C 29 May 2020 07:33:23.097 * DB saved on disk
13:C 29 May 2020 07:33:23.097 * RDB: 2 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
8:M 29 May 2020 07:33:23.158 * Background saving terminated with success
8:M 29 May 2020 07:33:23.158 * Synchronization with replica 172.16.4.48:6379 succeeded
8:M 29 May 2020 07:36:26.866 # Connection with replica 172.16.2.12:6379 lost.
8:M 29 May 2020 07:36:27.871 # Connection with replica 172.16.4.48:6379 lost.
8:S 29 May 2020 07:36:37.926 * Before turning into a replica, using my master parameters to synthesize a cached master: I may be able to synchronize with the new master with just a partial transfer.
8:S 29 May 2020 07:36:37.927 * REPLICAOF 172.16.2.12:6379 enabled (user request from 'id=21 addr=172.16.3.135:56721 fd=9 name=sentinel-5261eb21-cmd age=10 idle=0 flags=x db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=3 qbuf=151 qbuf-free=32617 obl=36 oll=0 omem=0 events=r cmd=exec')
8:S 29 May 2020 07:36:37.933 # CONFIG REWRITE executed with success.
8:S 29 May 2020 07:36:38.284 * Connecting to MASTER 172.16.2.12:6379
8:S 29 May 2020 07:36:38.284 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync started
8:S 29 May 2020 07:36:38.284 * Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
8:S 29 May 2020 07:36:38.285 * Master replied to PING, replication can continue...
8:S 29 May 2020 07:36:38.285 * Trying a partial resynchronization (request 563ca4b5f67f1e24c129729eaa74800b108902a3:52568).
8:S 29 May 2020 07:36:38.321 * Full resync from master: f21b8c35187b109b621605b375ef62e61b301834:52901
8:S 29 May 2020 07:36:38.321 * Discarding previously cached master state.
8:S 29 May 2020 07:36:38.356 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync: receiving 178 bytes from master
8:S 29 May 2020 07:36:38.356 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync: Flushing old data
8:S 29 May 2020 07:36:38.356 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync: Loading DB in memory
8:S 29 May 2020 07:36:38.356 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync: Finished with success
```

I am using redis 5.0. Earlier I was using redis 4.0 but I did not face such issue.

Comment: Are you sure master pod is deleted and didn't get recreated by replicaset or sth? Also, why do you think this is an issue? and what acording to you should be expected behaviour?

Comment: Once the master pod is down, sentinel sets one of the slaves to master. Since the pod of master is deleted, I should ideally have a new master and slave. But it shows there are 2 slaves. But it did not recreate the master pod.